# How to escape an underscore in a C preprocessor token?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The following snippet is supposed to take the value of PROJECT (defined in the Makefile)
and create an include file name. For example, if PROJECT=classifier, then it should at the end generate classifier_ir.h for PROJECTINCSTR

I find that this code works as long as I am not trying to use an underscore in the suffix. However the use of the underscore is not optional - our code base uses them everywhere. I can work around this because there are a limited number of values for PROJECT but I would like to know how to make the following snippet actually work, with the underscore. Can it be escaped?

```
#define PROJECT classifier

#define QMAKESTR(x) #x
#define MAKESTR(x) QMAKESTR(x)
#define MAKEINC(x) x ## _ir.h
#define PROJECTINC MAKEINC(PROJECT)
#define PROJECTINCSTR MAKESTR(PROJECTINC)

#include PROJECTINCSTR
```

Edit: The compiler should try to include classifier_ir.h, not PROJECT_ir.h.

Comment: I hope you guys have a good reason for doing this, because this is completely non-obvious to anyone who comes along later.  You're using a variable from the Makefile, performing some crazy macro magic, and this including a file named by the macro.  Someone new will have no idea what's happening.

Comment: We're striking a balance between having to edit by hand this include in every project that uses this code, or having it automagically do the right thing. Turns out this bit of trickery is not required, but I'm still interested to understand why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define QMAKESTR(x) #x
#define MAKESTR(x) QMAKESTR(x)
#define SMASH(x,y) x##y
#define MAKEINC(x) SMASH(x,_ir.h)
#define PROJECTINC MAKEINC(PROJECT)
#define PROJECTINCSTR MAKESTR(PROJECTINC)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and what I tried to do does not?

Comment: Basicly what is accomplished by introducing the "SMASH" definition is that _ir.h goes from being some random characters that the preoprocessor tries to tokenize to being a macro "symbol".

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#define QMAKESTR(x) #x
#define MAKESTR(x) QMAKESTR(x)
#define MAKEINC(x) x ## _ir.h
#define PROJECTINC(x) MAKEINC(x)
#define PROJECTINCSTR MAKESTR(PROJECTINC(PROJECT))

#include PROJECTINCSTR
```

Answer (score 0):

That barebone example works with gcc (v4.1.2) and tries to include "PROJECT_ir.h"